# How to launch a CD-ROM application which works only in MS-DOS or Windows 98?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-xp, dvd, ms-dos

Can be a DVD drive recognized as CD-ROM drive by Windows 98? I must return from Windows XP to Windows 98 the bootable diskette of which has the miraculous capability to recognize any CD-ROM drive. Is it possible in spite of the fact that in reality it would be the DVD drive? (My old Windows 98 machine is already out of order…) Thank you.

Comment: Not clear. What exactly are you trying to do and on what equipment?

Comment: Windows 98 should be able to handle DVD-ROM drives just as well as any other drive, so long as it has appropriate drivers. You'll need to find a valid way to get the driver onto the computer and installed before the drive will work. Nothing miraculous about it.

Comment: @harrymc I want to launch the Academic American encyclopedia on CD-ROM but I don't have already a strictly compatible platform. My Win98 computer is broken. That's why I am searching if the mentioned encyclopedia will be compatible with DVD drive on my WinXP computer if I make it to work under Win98 (if it is possible). Thank you.

Comment: You might have better chance with installing Windows 98 in a virtual machine.